# How can I make the lisp function immediately take effect?

Tags: init-file

When I add some lisp program in the init.el.  I don't want to restart emacs in order to make effect.  Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Drew's answer, if you add more than one expression, and don't want to have to evaluate them all individually, there's `eval-region`. Its docstring:

> Execute the region as Lisp code.

Select the region (move point to before the first expression, press `C-space`, move point to after the expression), then run `M-x eval-region`.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate it: call it with its arguments, using, for example `C-x C-e`. If the function `foo` takes arguments `arg1` and `arg2`, type `(foo arg1 arg2)`, put the cursor after `)`, and hit `C-x C-e`.

But if you are going to use some Emacs Lisp you really should start to read the Intro to Emacs Lisp manual - use `C-h i` then choose `Emacs Lisp Intro`.

Answer (score 1):

If your function has defvar or defcustom and you want those reset as part of the eval, then consider C-M-x (eval-defun). A plain eval will not reset previous values of the defvars, if any.